# How does browser calculate scrollbar's position when content height changes?

Tags: math, browser, scrolltop

I'm working on my own scrollbar for a game. And i can't figure out how to calculate scrollbar position (in browser scrollTop), when content's height changes. I want to show same position of scrollable content after changing its height.

As i can understand after some tests, if i add / remove element above viewport, then scrollTop value changes on height of added / removed element, if i add / remove element below viewport scrollTop value will be the same. How does browser detect, where element was added / removed? Maybe you have source, which explains how scrollbar math works in browser?

Thank you.

Comment: If we know the height of each content and spacing, it would not be hard to calculate for specific y position to be set between which two contents are. And the setter of the heights of every content should have callback, so that it will be automatically adapted whenever you try to change the height of specific content.

Comment: Sure, i know height of each element and if i add or remove element below, everything stay in viewport as it should. If i add or remove element above top of viewport, then coordinates of elements which are in viewport or below will change on height of added or removed element, so viewport will not show same content. In that case browser changes scrollbar position on height of added or removed element.

Comment: Yes, exactly. My explanation is based on Unity2d, but I think there would be not so much differences. Adding or removing the contents will be automatically call scrollbar-updating function by callback assigned to setter. Of course we know all informations to calculate the size and position of scrollbar.

Comment: And if i trigger scrollbar in each element on removing instead of just giving to scrollbar whole content height, what should i do next? Compare if position of element was above viewport, then add this value to scrollbar position?

Comment: I tried it and it works, but it's too complicated with systems that i have. I send to scrollbar all time just whole height of content and when i deleted elements, i just update this variable. So scrollbar didn't know about elements, he knew just about whole height.